# Remove unwanted parts of many file names

Tags: linux

I have file names like this:

```
MOD13Q1.A2013001.h25v08.005.2013018031021.hdf.250m_16_days_EVI.tif
MOD13Q1.A2013001.h25v08.005.2013018031021.hdf.250m_16_days_NDVI.tif
MOD13Q1.A2013001.h25v08.005.2013018031021.hdf.250m_16_days_VI_Quality.tif
MOD13Q1.A2013017.h25v08.005.2013039200748.hdf.250m_16_days_EVI.tif
MOD13Q1.A2013017.h25v08.005.2013039200748.hdf.250m_16_days_NDVI.tif
MOD13Q1.A2013017.h25v08.005.2013039200748.hdf.250m_16_days_VI_Quality.tif
```

I have need only specific details within the existing file name. I want the file names to be renamed like : `A2013001_h25v08_EVI.tif`

I have used the code

```
 for f in *.tif   
do    
c1= cut -c9-16 $f    
c2= cut -c18-23 $f     
c3= cut -c60-80 $f    
c= echo $c1$c2$c3 
echo mv "{$f}" "{$c}"  
done
```

But this code does not work. Is there another better method to do this? I am still new to Linux coding and hence any suggestions will be of great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have `mmv` installed, just do

```
mmv MOD13Q1.\*.*.005.2013039200748.hdf.250m_16_days_.*.tif \#1#2#3.tif
```

About your code:

```
for f in *.tif   
do    
c1= cut -c9-16 $f    
c2= cut -c18-23 $f     
c3= cut -c60-80 $f
```

Here, the backticks are missing:

```
c1=`echo "$f" | cut -c9-16`
c2=`echo "$f" | cut -c18-23`    
c3=`echo "$f" | cut -c60-80`
```

Alternatively, you could use

```
c1=$(echo "$f" | cut -c9-16)
c2=$(echo "$f" | cut -c18-23)    
c3=$(echo "$f" | cut -c60-80)

c= echo $c1$c2$c3
```

Here,

```
c=$c1$c2$c3
```

is enough.

Some other notes: You should become accustomed to using `"` around your variables unless explicitly not wanted.

If you had files like

```
MOD13Q1 A2013001 h25v08 005 2013018031021 hdf 250m_16_days_EVI.tif
```

(which would be perfectly valid and legitime)

your code would fail to work with them:

```
for i in *.tif; do
    mv "$i" "$i".bak
    mv $i $i.bak
end
```

would do two completely different things: the first one would actually rename the file, whicle the latter one would try to execute

```
mv MOD13Q1 A2013001 h25v08 005 2013018031021 hdf 250m_16_days_EVI.tif MOD13Q1 A2013001 h25v08 005 2013018031021 hdf 250m_16_days_EVI.tif.bak
```

which means to move/rename the files `MOD13Q1`, `A2013001`, `h25v08`, `005`, `2013018031021`, `hdf`, `250m_16_days_EVI.tif`, `MOD13Q1`, `A2013001`, `h25v08`, `005`, `2013018031021` and `hdf` to `250m_16_days_EVI.tif.bak`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `mmv`:

```
mmv -n "MOD13Q1.*.005.*.hdf.250m_16_days_*.tif" "#1_#3.tif"
```

If the output looks correct, remove the `-n` to actually rename the files.

Note: `mmv` isn't a standard command, you may have to install it using the system's package manager.